# Content Security Policy directive 'object-src' contains an invalid source:

Tags: content-security-policy

**Getting below error in console.**
The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'object-src' contains an invalid source: 'https://*.hereapi.com'none''. It will be ignored.

below code configured

```
objectSrc: "object-src 'self' https://vltcdn-public.s3.amazonaws.com https://*.hereapi.com",
```

do we need add any space after .com " ?
can anyone suggest please

It shouldnt throw error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave a space at the end, it will resolve.

```
objectSrc: "object-src 'self' https://vltcdn-public.s3.amazonaws.com https://*.hereapi.com ",
```